# Extruded sphere has loop with no normals - how to fix?

Tags: normals

I've extruded a sphere which I later deform with a shape-keyed lattice. All's well, except that when deformed, I see a discontinuity in the shading. Inspecting the face normals, I see the following:

[image]

You can see that there's a loop which has two odd characteristics:

1. It has both edge and face markers;
2. It has no normals (and they're not just pointing the other way, they really appear to be absent).

Selecting everything and recalculating the normals had no effect.

If I select an edge segment along that loop and delete the edge, one of the adjacent faces gets deleted too.

I *think* this is an edge from which I extruded to lengthen the tube.

How can I repair this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a similar object by extruding from a circle,dragging upwards then extruding and not dragging, then extruding a third time and dragging up.

The resulting ring of faces with no surface area I removed by selecting **All** then going to the **Tools** panel > **Remove** > **Remove Doubles**.